# In informatica, my mapping took long time to fetch rows but reads within a minute

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

In my mapping it tooks long time to fetch rows to the target table but it reads those rows from .CSV file within a minute.In this mapping One source is a flat file another source is a table which is having data from target.Here we create a logic to UPDATE or DELETE or INSERT in target based on comparison on the data from flat file and the source table(data from target table).while seeing sesion log it reads data from flat file within a minute but it fetches those data to the target to taget 9 rows/sec throughput.Here the target table is created using unix script ie `CREATE TABLE STG_LM_INSTITUTION as (SELECT * FROM LM_INSTITUTION);`Target in this mapping is STG_LM_INSTITION.this is the copy of final target(LM_INSTITUTION).I think the problem is due to creation of the taget table in script but i'm not sure.Anyone please help me to solve this issue.Source flat file has 2L rows. I run this mapping with 2L rows.After 11hrs it fetches only 1L records into the target.But while running using 500rws only it fetches records in one minute to the target .[image]

Comment: ya absolutly it's a sequence.why I need to change into seq gen transforamtion? Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Thanks Marek.SQL_LM_INST_SEQ is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SQL_LM_INST_SEQ` retrieves PK values from an Oracle sequence and that's costly, because for every inserted row a roundtrip to the database is necessary to get a new ID.

Use a Sequence Generator transformation instead - Integration Service will generate IDs on its own.

Comment: Hi Marek.This is worked for first two itrations.While running in the third time it tooks long time like before the change.How to solve this???

Comment: I'm running test with the same source file.

Comment: I'm running test with the same source file.both are same tables only. STG_FLAG_LM_INSTITUTION = STG_FLAG_LM_INSTITUTION and STG_LM_INSTITUTION =  STG_FLAG_LM_INSTITUTION.while in the third run when after updating ( small chanegs in source file to verify it's updates correctly).But it took long time

Comment: Am i doing corerectly by using same table for source and target.

Comment: Test it step by step: no changes, only new rows, only changed rows, only rows for deletion. Is the performance slow in each case?

Comment: When I do fresh INSERT it runs within 26secs.When I changed any row data for UPDATE check, all the rows are went as DELETE but actually it should not happen.also runs a longer time,I aborted that load

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using update strategy transformation.
Do you trying to update the target?
Probably you have to build right index on your target table table.

Comment: There are only two main column SITE_CODE,SITE_NAME and another PK column is INST_ID which generated using sql trans.INST_ID is not present in source file